# How to retrieve parameters passed to AAD with Open ID Connect within the redirect Controller?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am using Open Id Connect with Azure Active Directory for authentication. I am also setting a parameter to the OpenIdConnectChallengeProperties, so that I can retrieve this parameter in the controller action which is the redirect URL. 
I did not find any information on how to do this.
My code is as follows.

**AuthController.cs**

```
 [Route("auth/signin")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignIn([FromBody] RequestParams requestParams)
        {
            Guid guid = new Guid();
            _cache.Set(guid, requestParams);
            var baseURL = Request.Host;
            var redirectURL = "https://" +  baseURL + "/auth/redirect";
            var properties = new OpenIdConnectChallengeProperties();
            properties.SetParameter("id",guid);
            properties.RedirectUri = redirectURL;
            return Challenge(properties, AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme);
        }

[Route("auth/redirect")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<string> HandleAADRedirect()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
                string idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
            }
            return _cache.Get("").ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user authenticates and goes back to your server, you can then [access](https://hajekj.net/2018/06/12/passing-state-through-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) the property.

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var value = result.Properties.Items["id"];
```